# How declear the char array?

Tags: java, char

Hi please explain me how to declare the char array like this.In java?

```
char szData[50] = "*KW,NR09G00001,001,082309#"
```

Comment: Why 50? What about the remaining places in the array, what value will they have?

Comment: `K` is one char, How you are going to add these characters in the array?

Comment: It must be array of chars,not strings
char szData[50] = {'*','K','W',',','N' .. etc};

Comment: i need 50 size how to add

Answer (score 4):

```
char[] szData = "*KW,NR09G00001,001,082309#".toCharArray();
```

If you need array with 50 elements, than:

```
char[] szData = Arrays.copyOf("*KW,NR09G00001,001,082309#".toCharArray(), 50);
```

Comment: char szData[50] - C-style declaration

Comment: I want 50 size how to add?

Comment: @user3475175 - You can't.  This is Java not C.

Comment: 2a 4b 57 2c 4e 52 30 39 47 30 30 30 30 31 __ 2c 30 31 35 2c 30 38 30 37 35 
36 2c 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 __ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 //command string 50byte(*KW,NR09G00001,015,080756,#) I need to generate like this

Comment: @StephenC actually you can. This is just not the same philosophy as C, so it requires a bit of extra work.

Comment: @StephenC I see. The OP was asking *how* to do so, so there are actually solutions, but not that one, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

In case that the fixed array size `50` has any important reason for you:

```
char[] szdata = new char[50];
char sc[] = "*KW,NR09G00001,001,082309#".toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<szdata.length;i++) {
    if (i<sc.length) szdata[i]=sc[i];
}
```

Comment: Maybe `System.arraycopy()` would be appropriate here ;)

Comment: Right, but I think this explains better.

Comment: Well, I think `System.arraycopy` is pretty much self-explanatory, and the OP would get the meaning of the line in a second. As for the parameters details, the javadoc would help the OP.